# How to pass a string from .mxml to .as class in adobe air flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I want to pass a string from .mxml to a .as class..For that i tried using[Bindable]..But i

get only null value.How can i get the string from mxml?

```
I have given the link to show u what i have tried:

 http://192.150.16.67/devnet/flex/articles/databinding_pitfalls.html
```

Comment: Q1) Do you want to bind string or you just want to pass value from MXML to .as Class. If you want to just pass string, You can use set and get method. Create instance of Class and pass value from MXML to .as class.

Comment: Thank you Mahesh, I want to pass the string when i click a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below code this may help you for your question.

**Main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var stringReaderObject:StringReader;
            private function clickHandler():void
            {
                if(!stringReaderObject)
                {
                    stringReaderObject = new StringReader();
                }
                stringReaderObject.readString = inputTextID.text;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Group x="50" y="50">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:TextInput id="inputTextID"/>
        <s:Button label="Click" click="clickHandler()"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

*Class Name:* - **StringReader.as**

```
package
{
    public class StringReader
    {
        private var _readString:String;
        public function StringReader()
        {
        }

        public function set readString(value:String):void
        {
            _readString = value;
            trace(_readString);
        }

        public function get readString():String
        {
            return _readString;
        }
    }
}
```

trace will identify how you can pass value from MXML to .as class.

it can be achievable by another 2 ways those are as below: -

1) By creating public variable in you class.
2) By creating global in your application and access it in your class.

hope this may help you.